# proper way to store large outlook archives

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

Hosted google apps email, imap downloads to outlook 2003 (mainly) and 2007. My .pst archive per year is increasing steadily from 1GB (2007) to 2GB (2008) to 3GB to 6GB.

I expect it to go well over 10GB per pst file in the next few years. Is there any good method for me to archive the pst files, and do english/chinese searches on the contents?

Currently what I'm doing is I load the pst files in outlook and leave it there. So I have a current year, last year, and last last year folder in outlook. And that's just one email account, I only have about 10 email accounts in my company but I can foresee it would be horrible to administer all of them.

I'm open to alternate commercial/opensourced software suggestions or running some kind of archival server on another machine, but the clients should optimally be still using some version of app based outlook.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run fetchmail to fetch all your account mails into Maildirs
2. (optional) Run an imap server that reads all these maildirs. see below.

From here you have two options:

1. For the less technically inclined users, create an imap account in their outlook. Use outlook to search.
2. For the tech user, use command line tools like mu - http://code.google.com/p/mu0/

Answer (score 0):

There is no definite right/good answer for your question. But I will throw in one idea.

Configure a [Zimbra](https://www.zimbra.com/) server.
When creating account in Zimbra, you have 2 choices

1. Create one login account, within it, create external IMAP accounts for all your gmail accounts
2. Create one account for each gmail account and create external IMAP account in each of them

Email will be pull in automatically in both cases.

**Pro**: Zimbra has good web interface and search function, can be access from multiple device, including mobile ones(come with mobile web interface). Open source, Free

**Con**: Additional hardware, not easy to config if you are not familiar with network.